# JSON deserialization throws exception when nested object is empty

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, restsharp

Hello I have a problem with deserializing JSON to object.

I have this kind of JSON:

```
{
"my_obj":{
    "id":"test",
    "nested_obj":{
        "value":"testValue",
        "desc":"testDesc"}
    }
}
```

But sometimes I receive empty nested_obj:

```
{
"my_obj":{
    "id":"test",
    "nested_obj":""
    }
}
```

My code to handle this:

```
public class MyObj
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public NestedObj nested_obj { get; set; }
}

public class NestedObj
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
}

public virtual T Execute<T>(IRestRequest request) where T : new()
{
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    var response = _client.Execute<T>(request);

    LogResponse(response);
    CheckResponseException(response);

    return response.Data;
}
```

When the nested_obj is not empty, then deserialization works perfectly fine. But when nested_obj is empty, I receive this exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'.

Is it possible to deserialize it this way? Unfortunately it is not possible to change response of the WebService, so i should parse it correctly in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use Newtonsoft's [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). It works fine. Here's a short snippet from LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(@"{
        property: ""apweiojfwoeif"",
        nested: {
            prop1: ""wpeifwjefoiwj"",
            prop2: ""9ghps89e4aupw3r""
        }
    }").Dump();
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(@"{
        property: ""apweiojfwoeif"",
        nested: """"
    }").Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class A {
    public string Property {get;set;}
    public B Nested {get;set;}
}

class B {
    public string Prop1 {get;set;}
    public string Prop2 {get;set;}
}
```

And the result is

[image: results]

Answer (score 1):

Ouch. That has nothing to do with your code as you already know. It's just that the web service is sometimes defining nested_obj as a NestedObj object, and sometimes as a string (when it sends null). So your parser doesn't know what to make of it.

Your best bet might be to write a custom parser for it. (which makes sense since it's not standard JSON due to the type morphing).

There's a section on writing a custom parser for RestSharp [here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization)

They tell you to implement `IDeserializer` but I'd suggest you simply extend `JsonDeserializer` to add your special custom functionality and delegate back to the super class for everything else.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it was really helpfull. But the real solution was @SOReader answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Reason is because in

```
{
"my_obj":{
    "id":"test",
    "nested_obj":{
        "value":"testValue",
        "desc":"testDesc"}
    }
}
```

nested object is receiving an object type

while in

```
{
"my_obj":{
    "id":"test",
    "nested_obj":""
    }
}
```

it is receiving string type.

if

it returns

```
{
"my_obj":{
    "id":"test",
    "nested_obj":null
    }
}
```

then it will be able to parse successfully.

try using http://json2csharp.com/ to convert both of your json and see the difference

Comment: or you can change the type of nestedobject to type object, that will work

Comment: I believe he cannot change incoming JSON's format. So we need to deal with empty strings

Comment: Exactly, I cannot modify the JSON sent from WebService. I could modify the response manually in my app, but I can see no point of doing that.

Comment: `public class MyObj
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public object nested_obj { get; set; }
}` try this, not checked, but i hope this will work